# What is the proper use of punctuations inside a “quote”?

Tags: punctuation

Which of these sentences are using the proper usage of punctuation?

> Nicolo said, "I'll let you know if anything changes."
>
> Nicolo said, "I'll let you know if anything changes".
>
> Nicolo said, "I'll let you know if anything changes.".

Or is there a certain rule when all of the sentence is correct especially when writing novels or stories.

Comment: Period inside the quotes only, as it is punctuation of that phrase. In such cases, the period after the quote is not needed.

Comment: @user3169. Do you mean this will be the same answer when using other punctuations?

Answer (score 1):

This depends which side of the pond you're on. If I understand correctly, British speakers usually put the punctuation outside, but there are exceptions.  Americans, on the other hand, are taught to put periods (that's "full stops" if you're British) and commas inside the quotation mark.

This dates back to the days of mechanical printing using hand-set movable type. Supposedly, if a perod or comma were put outside a quote mark, it might break off.

Another quaint convention that dates back to those days is the double space after a sentence-ending period.  This makes no sense with modern computerized fonts, but it is still a proofing option in word processing; e.g. Microsoft Word.

Comment: From what you said, do you mean the first sentence is correct in British English and the second is correct in American English and the third one is wrong?